# How to find an object in an array that implements an interface and matches a condition

Tags: typescript

I'm still learning how to do TDD with a strongly typed language like typescript. One of the problems I ran into is that although using interfaces makes it easy to quickly create test fakes, if those interfaces grow as you add more functionality, those tests become fragile as the fakes keep needing to be updated with additional methods/attributes that are irrelevant to most of the tests. So I think the solution is to have multiple small interfaces for specific behaviors and have my concrete objects just implement multiple interfaces.

However, the problem is now that I want to keep a collection of generic objects, but find within this collection, an object that implements a specific interface that also passes some condition.

In my case, I have entities that implement the `Entity` interface. Some entities can be interacted with, and these also implement the `Interactable` interface.

I have a type predicate for `Interactable` defined as such:

```
function isInteractable(entity: any): entity is Interactable {
    return "getInteractHint" in entity;
}
```

Say I have an array of entities, and a condition I need the entity to fulfil:

```
const entities: Entity[] = [ ... ]

const condition = (entity: Entity): boolean => ...some test...
```

I want to do something like:

```
getInteractable(entities: Entity[]): Interactable | undefined {
    return entities.filter(isInteractable).find(condition);
}
```

But the problem is that that isn't enough to cast the result to `Interactable` or `Entity & Interactable`; Typescript will complain that an object of type `Entity` doesn't implement `Interactable`.

I'm left with this horrible construction to make sure that I get the right types out at the end:

```
type InteractableEntity = Entity & Interactable;
type InteractablesOrNull = InteractableEntity | null;
const castEntities: InteractablesOrNull[] = ctx.entities.map(e => {
    if (isInteractable(e)) {
        return e;
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
});
const filteredInteractables: InteractableEntity[] = castEntities.filter(e => e !== null);

return filteredInteractables.find(condition);
```

The intermediate objects here make the code a lot harder to read.

What is a better, more consise, way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is touched on in [microsoft/TypeScript#29501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29501), which was deemed a design limitation of TypeScript.

---

The [library typings for `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8f8a579eee719bd2c95c7a0b0e27de4f0bdc14aa/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1362-L1373) have two call signatures:

```
interface Array<T> {

  // narrowing
  filter<S extends T>(
     predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
     thisArg?: any
  ): S[];
  
  // non-narrowing
  filter(
    predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): T[];

}
```

The first call signature is the narrowing behavior you want, where you pass a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as a callback, and the return type of the array changes.  The second call signature is the usual situation in which the callback does not do anything about the type, and the return type of the array is unchanged.

The first call signature is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `S`, the type in the `is` clause of the guard function output.  In your case, this is `Interactable`.  And note that `S` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T`, the element type of the array.  In your case, this is `Entity`.  And here's the problem, `Entity extends Interactable` is not true, so the compiler cannot select this call signature.  Thus it falls back to the second call signature, and no narrowing happens:

```
const oops = entities.filter(isInteractable) // Entity[]
```

---

If there were a call signature in between these two that accepted an arbitrary type `S` which is not required to extend `T`, and returned an array whose elements are [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `S` and `T`, like this:

```
filter<S>(
    predicate: (value: any, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S,
    thisArg?: any
): (S & T)[];
```

then your code would work with no issues.

```
const interactables = entities.filter(isInteractable)
// const interactables: (Interactable & Entity)[]
```

So one fix here is that you can try to [merge in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own call signature declaration into `Array`.  But really, this use case is probably not very common, and you might not want to alter the way your whole code base calls `Array.filter()` just for this one situation.

---

Another approach here is to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `isInteractable` is a value of the required type so that the compiler will select the right `filter()` call signature.  Instead of `(x: any) => x is Interactable`, you want something like `(x: Entity) => x is Interactable & Entity)`:

```
const interactables = entities.filter(
    isInteractable as (x: Entity) => x is Interactable & Entity)
// const interactables: (Interactable & Entity)[]
```

This would be my recommendation if you're only going to be doing this sort of thing once in your code.

---

Another possibility is to change the definition of `isInteractable` to be a more generic type guard which acts in such a way as to produce an intersection if the input type does not have obvious overlap with the output type:

```
function isInteractable<T>(entity: T): entity is
    Interactable extends T ? Interactable : (Interactable & T) {
    return "getInteractHint" in entity;
}
```

The new `isInteractable()` will narrow `entity` of type `T` either to `Interactable` or to `Interactable & T`, depending on whether or not `Interactable` is narrower than `T`.  This also fixes the issue:

```
const interactables = entities.filter(isInteractable); 
// const interactables: (Interactable & Entity)[]
```

I'd only recommend this if you plan to use `isInteractable` as a `filter()` predicate in multiple places.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmoscBGAbFAbwFgAoZC5AcwjHUiiwAlQwAuZAZzClCoG4yAXzJlW0eEmQBRcMDABPZCXKUIHbrxADho0iDgBbCJwAOiFAHleVAGrROwAPYhleyshgBXEAjDPXYE56TD9cAgAKCDlFDjgQBQBKDmj-RWQgtAxGMPwiMg8PKFovKFcAIho6bOZWcozXVPkFQVUKEVICygATCAQ8OGLkBBduZCb-Ew5ZNIUAbQBdVo9e-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-oAMrjNe0R3sg1ERPSHhLiucZAgmSYppR6a3leOZ5gWUBFr6tIcJR5YXNcUnJhkxpca+bSFI2zaoe274JPSXZcYsTzGcy9FKkx2jIOxLFhhx3GXMJxmiVGwAxhJES6Sm8QKHJWaKfmhbvmp3yaQsFY6YmemZIZImUKZnAthZ4XWQcPGYpRiR2XodEuAAtE5jHMcZrEMOxvlwhQYmBau8apTJkUKRySmxcW6mCVplbVrW9aZRQ2W5R2oEeF2iX2RB+q8vyVLGucpppOanChmxTUgva4KOmQzIrdBnAHF+x0oJiIGlQsehQWtgxOHByDwexRacPKUDPsKsb6dduI3BAAMasacCQ1wPCBWAu4csWtWuReZAreIYK4pwlggCgm0TDte02vSh3Yt+77GhE2bdkk2nIJm+lYqEN0YjTiSnSi6NHVjOMphEwN5Kz91umBz0Cq973wQAzMhcBUigcDIIY-IbE4himHg7WQFuF7IG1QVzgD3IA7eBDGtlwxQ0RpDeL4-guED3N5FRPlfBpXZfPp9ICwQvFAcalHIK2TOY4LV1O77xUwvSxQEWUyCVLQ10sOA9SgFtzStBBrzrMMowAWaUw02VpA5+8+d57eewuAcbts3Ttz3BAjx6FzZM3RtGeTLtDXhqTzO4ok-AUkCPu3WzIsYzieScHMAAMCzEknR0p9yYvrXott+AE1DL+3uKQnsRcgeWHBj8gAA+VbyVauNbrClCx6UjSFz3nm2mPiShreEQ7NXIBD10GBPQQA)

Comment: Wow, that's a comprehensive answer :). I've accepted because I think the last option with the alternative `isInteractable` definition is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I did come up with a better solution than the horrible mess I had in the question (although I think the solution by @jcalz is better).

Instead of:

```
return entities.filter(isInteractable).find(condition);
```

Which returns a type of `Entity`, I could have done:

```
const target = entities.filter(isInteractable).find(condition);
if (target && isInteractable(target)) {
    return target;
}
```

Calling `isInteractable` twice feels like a violation of DRY, although it should be perfectly safe.